# Inno Setup test for next available drive letter

Tags: inno-setup

What is the best way to go about testing for the next available drive letter in Inno Setup?

I have thought about doing this from the command line (e.g. [Next available drive letter after C: drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235729/next-available-drive-letter-after-c-drive)), outputting to a file and then reading the string in from the file, but it seems like a messy way of doing this. Is there a better, more elegant solution?

Comment: In [`this example`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21867468/960757) you can find how to get list of fixed drives.

Comment: Thanks @TLama. That looks a little beyond my basic programming skills, so before I invest some time into this, are you able to tell me if it would work for just returning the next free drive letter in order to map a drive to a network share?

Comment: Ah, I got your question wrong (I thought you want to get next available drive, but you want to get next free drive letter). But yes, it could be used for that, but it's overcomplicated. The `GetLogicalDrives` function is the right choice here, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks, in that case, I will look at how I might be able to use that function.